# Successive contractibles: Example - "It's not" versus "It isn't"

Tags: grammar, contractions

My apologies if this has been asked before.

Consider a simple model sentence like

> It is not good.

Is it better to contract the first pair of words as

> It's not good.

Or the second pair as

> It isn't good.

Comment: Offhand I'd say there isn't much difference, but bear in mind that you can't stress any element that is contracted, so if, in a real sentence, you wanted to stress *not*, you'd have to go for *it's not good*